# 3rd Party App Tokens within AppSync with User Pools

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

after some reading on [Using multiple authorization types with AWS AppSync GraphQL APIs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/using-multiple-authorization-types-with-aws-appsync-graphql-apis/) and [The Complete Guide to User Authentication with the Amplify Framework](https://dev.to/dabit3/the-complete-guide-to-user-authentication-with-the-amplify-framework-2inh) , one thing I could not figure out is if I can have 3rd Party Application Tokens (e.g. like Twitter API) and use AppSync+Cognito to generate credentials for service-to-service mutations/query?

I already have a user flow via Cognito (type AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS). I want to centralize service-to-service calls using my AppSync. Limiting the service/token access would be great too (to only X Mutations, instead of the whole schema). Would that be possible?

I'm a bit lost around what are the current limitations.

- do I need a Custom Authorizer in Cognito?
- should I move everything to IAM credentials?
- a Lambda Resolver with manual credentials check + AppSync call?
- I can't do it and I need to store these tokens in a different place (DynamoDB, etc), with metadata/some id to have some kind of identity and always use Lambda Resolvers etc.

thoughts and insights are more than welcome,
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today, AppSync [does support 4 types of user authentication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/security.html#aws-appsync-security)

- API key (no authentication)
- IAM credentials
- OpenID tokens
- Cognito User Pool tokens

There is [a request to add custom lambda authorisers](https://github.com/aws/aws-appsync-community/issues/2) as well, but nothing has been announced to date.

In your scenario, I would use Cognito User Pool authentication on the App Sync side and federate Cognito User pool with Twitter OIDC. I know a couple of years ago Twitter was only supporting a custom subset of Oauth2.  I'll let you check if they do support OIDC now :-)

But you're not the only asking this question

- https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=881666
- [User pools for users who register via twitter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41338234/user-pools-for-users-who-register-via-twitter)

Comment: thanks for the input Sébastien! perhaps I didn't quoted my question correctly. I would like to generate App Tokens for my clients (external services) to access my AppSync API for a service-to-service communication (I tried to use Twitter API as an example, where you generate App Tokens and can use private/authenticated endpoints).

I'm happy with my Cognito User Pool for UI flow and since we've some mutations there, I was thinking in deprecate an API Gateway we've for service-to-service, and use AppSync for it,

make sense to you?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question.  So, you don't have much todo.  AppSync can natively consume tokens generated by Cognito User Pool. Check the doc here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/security.html#amazon-cognito-user-pools-authorization and Nader posted many content on the web, such as this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VKhLqBG7sdI